# Server side validation PHP with target attribute

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to used a server side validation on php where in my form has a action and target attribute. My form looks like this.

```
<form action="destination.php" method="POST" target="blank">
/* inputs here
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I tried to used validation on the same page as the form. But since it has a target="blank" attribute. It is not working. Any idea on how can I make a server side validation on this way? thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    /* validation here..
}
```

Comment: Why `target="blank"`? What are you trying to accomplish with that? Doesn't make sense for a lot of reasons...

Comment: @user3627265 try add `value="submit"` in `input`

Comment: sidenote: `target=blank` ain't valid. should be `target="_blank"`. Samples: `<form target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">`

Comment: I used target="blank" to load the data on new tab. Thats what I'm trying to do. May I know why it is invalid?

Comment: thats just a sidenote, for more reference you could check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes) for more information

Comment: The output stills the same.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<form action="destination.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="data">
</form>
```

/* destination.php */

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    /* validation here..
}
```